# popViewController doesn't work in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. Calling self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method has no effect.

My Main.storyboard looks like: UIViewController -> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController. How can I go back to UIViewController tapping on a UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Have you tried to call `[self dismissViewController]` from within the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` table view delegate method?

Comment: It doesn't work. My TableViewController is pushed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`popViewController` dismisses 1 viewController from the navigationViewController's stack. Since your tableViewController is the only viewController in this stack, popping it wont do anything.

What you want to do is dismiss your navigationController, which is most likely presented modally. You can achieve this by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated`

Comment: My TableViewController isn't presented modally, it is pushed. Will dismissViewController work in this case ?

Comment: Your tableViewController is not presented modally indeed, but your navigationController is, and you want to dismiss the latter one instead of the tableViewController. Calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` should work yes.